# Upload image links placed in text file to imgur

Tags: script, api, imgur

Is there any way to upload images to imgur account when image links are placed in text file or copied in clipboard . Also give output something like this for all files . Platform - Windows 7 . Can install any software needed .

```
  original-image-link           imgur-link
```

PS- I have tried EasyImgur . Gave me error 400 when tried multiple image links .

Answer (score 0):

In cygwin
`cat file.txt`  displays the file onscreen
`grep "http*"` searches output of cat for all instances of http followed by * (wildcard)
`wget -o "C:/users/(you)/downloads/imgur"` downloads all of the links found by grep and `--outputs` them into `C:/path/to/downloads/folder`
But I don't know how to make imgur share a folder as I don't use imgur

proper implementation would be

```
cat C:/path/to/file |grep "http*" | wget -o "output folder"
```

Then in imgur: upload folder?
C:/path/to/"outputfolder"